# Capture slow motion videos in Android

Tags: android, camera, video-capture, mediarecorder

I need to capture slow motion videos in Android. I tried the MediaRecorder and I set a higher frame rate using setVideoFrameRate() method. But it doesn't capture slow motion videos in that frame rate.

But in Galaxy Note 2, there's is an option to record slow motion videos up to 1/8 X. I need a similar thing like that but I can't find how they are doing it.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Shashika

Comment: Keep in mind that in different devices cameras are capable of different maximum frame rate.  Normal video is between 24 and 30 fps.  To really see something in slow motion, you need to get at least 100-120 fps.  Very few devices have cameras that are capable of doing this.  What you can do though is to record at normal speed (say, 30 fps) and then extrapolate it to 120 fps by parsing the video and replicating each frame 4 times.  This will not be the same as a real 120 fps recording though.

Comment: If we check the Galaxy Note 2 slow motion video, the frame rate is around 15. So may be they are replicating frames like you said.

Comment: The other alternative would be to record the video at 30fps and play it as, say, 10 fps - this will provide you a 3x slow motion.